# Windows Remote Desktop Onblur Event Tracking

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server

The case is like this: I am about to give an external party a remote desktop access to review my sensitive document (procedure & policy for incident handling). I want to prevent them to take screenshot on my document. Unfortunately, I still can not prevent if they

set the remote desktop window on windowed mode then put the window on blur (by opening other application, or click on the desktop, or use another monitor and open a new app then press screenshot button or any other screenshot application.

Is there any solution for at least know if the third party is taking a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone can see & read a document on their screen, then they can screenshot it or even just take a photo with their phone & you will never know.

Comment: I know, but can we at least actually try to know if they screenshot it (with the defined condition above)? If they are taking with their phone or camera, I agree, we can't do anything.

Comment: I fail to see how you can possibly know when someone takes a screenshot. There is absolutely no reason for their computer to transmit that information anywhere.

Comment: I see, I am also with you, I do not see any way as well. Because of that, I am asking for any suggestion. But my idea is, maybe the remote desktop can silently capture the keystroke or maybe only the screenshot key and somehow log it even when the remote desktop window is onblur. If it is impossible, then so be it, that is the risk i have to accept.

Comment: You're clutching at straws. if someone can see your document, it may as well be theirs.

Comment: Okayy, so there is no way to even log it?

Comment: No. You have no control over their computer.